# Jquery load using selectors

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, css-selectors

I would like to know how or if it is possible to use selectors in an ajax request with jQuery

What I would like to achieve, is something like this

```
$(".classname").load("something.html $(".classname:contains('some text')").parent()");
```

In other words I would like to pass a complex selector to the requested page other than just a class or an id.

Can anybody help, or is this just impossible? I can't seem to find any other thread where this has been asked!

Comment: can you explain more indepth what the use case is?

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd need to pass a selector to the requested page... What is the requested page going to do with the selector string?

Comment: Have you tried it? According to the docs: 'If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.'
@Khôi see http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: It looks like it should work, Have you tried it?

Comment: @gdoron The problem is that it's not a selector but (or should be) a jquery object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.get` instead if the selector is complex.

```
$.get("something.html", function(data){
  $(".classname").html($(".classname:contains('some text')", data).parent().html());
}, "html");
```

Comment: This worked really well - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :) - I'm still a rookie at this, so can you explain what the data parameter does?

Comment: The data is the content of `something.html`, the responseText.

Answer (score 3):

[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) assumes the text following a space following the URL is a selector. It has to be a [textual selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You have accidentally included the javascript equivalent in the string instead. Try this:

```
$('.classname').load('something.html .classname:contains("some text"):parent');
```

Comment: :parent will not select the parent but only reduce the set to elements that are parents.

Comment: Ok, this works almost as intended, apart from the :parent part - I only get the classname that contains the text i'm looking for, not the parent!??

Comment: @afcdesign you can use :has (see my answer)

Comment: I don't quite understand? I just want to get the parent of the selector. How is this achieved with :has?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.classname').load('something.html *:has(.classname:contains("some text"))')
```